# .NetCore working with multiple environment issue - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT always takes production on host server

Tags: server, host, pcf, aspnetcore-environment

I tried referring the solution suggested on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1 with the section Set the environment.Also, I added the below part of code in Project file/publish profile

For Windows IIS deployments: Include the  property in the publish profile (.pubxml) or project file. This approach sets the environment in web.config when the project is published:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**when I deploy the solution on host server which is PCF (pivotal cloud foundry). .Netcore runtime is always taking the hosting environment as "Production" instead of Development**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use it as environment variable then would suggest to do this

1. Use below command to set the environment variable in PCF:

   ```
    cf set-env ENV_RUN development
   ```
2. Read across the environment value in the application using -

   ```
   Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENV_RUN");
   ```

Comment: Great! would benefit others too if you can accept the answer